# ¿Qué significado de "mañana" fue antes: el de "día siguiente" o el de "primera hora del día"? ¿Cuándo y cómo se originó el otro?

Tags: etimología, significado, historia, sustantivos, adverbios

En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26927/12637) hemos visto que, al contrario que en otros idiomas, en español usamos [la misma palabra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OJHi0DU) para hablar de:

- la parte del día comprendida entre el amanecer y el mediodía, y
- el día que sigue inmediatamente al de hoy.

Estas dos acepciones ya aparecían en el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495:

[image: Mañana]

Según la etimología de la palabra:

> Del lat. vulg. *[hora] *maneāna* '[a hora] temprana'.

parece que el primer significado fue el de "hora temprana del día". ¿Es esto así? Y si lo es, en algún momento se debió añadir a su lista de acepciones la de "el día siguiente al de hoy". ¿Cuándo y cómo ocurrió eso?

Comment: interesante, pedro tiene reazon, tenemos una palabra para mañana que no es mañana : http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cras

Comment: Y en italiano tienen _domattina_ para _mañana por la mañana_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo primero sería ver que en latín el día siguiente es *cras* y en las lenguas romances el término haya "desaparecido" (sobre esto hablamos luego), por tanto sería cuestión de buscar desde otra lengua latina.

El francés *Demain* se origina, según [esta página](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/demain.html) de la palabra latina *mane*, es decir a primera hora y citando del artículo (la traducción no es la mejor pero espero que la idea se entienda)

> El uso del término en la mañana para designar el día siguiente es común. Se encuentra en alemán *Morgen*, danés y noruego *i morgen*, sueco *Morgon*, holandés *Morgen*. El *Tomorrow* inglés también está relacionado con la partícula  mar- de *morning*, está relacionado con la idea de la luz, de algo que brilla.

Es decir que el cambio no afectó solo al mundo latino sino también aplica otras familias lingüísticas. Y aunque parece que en latín *mane* ya hacía intentos para ser la palabra que designara al día siguiente y aunque nuestro objetivo es en español, se menciona que en frances *Demain* ya era aceptada hacia el 1080.

Ahora, sobre cuando se asienta el mañana en términos de futuro en español, vale aclarar que la única lengua que preservó el cras, como decía Pedro, es el español, y si buscamos en escritos entre la época del cid y el diccionario de Nebrija (época en la cual el mañana ya debe ser popular) encontramos en *El Libro del Buen Amor* del Arcipreste de Hita (mediados del siglo XIV) se menciona la frase:

> *si oy casar la quieren, cras de otro se enamora*,

además *de hoy en cras* (una especie de refrán) lo que nos da a entender que el término se populariza después. El *Rimado de Palacio* de Pedro Lopez (final del siglo XIV) aparece

> *Los que los sus pecados non quieren confesar
>
>   e cras e cras diziendo lo quieren alongar*

Solamente hasta la segunda mitad del siglo XV aparece escrito el mañana sin el cras (en La Celestina y a la Gramática de Nebrija). En obras como el Conde Lucanor o el Libro del Buen Amor, mañana es temprano. Así pues, la palabra no se nota sino hacia el siglo XV (en escrito) y ya entramos en especulaciones, pero lo más probable es que el cambio a nivel popular fuese incluso desde los mismos tiempos que en Francia.

Answer (score 6):

Como sus raíces latinas, el primer significado fue el de *"hora temprana del día"*.

Puedes confirmar esto buscando los términos en el CORDE. *cras* se usaba hasta el medio del siglo XIV, cuando *mañana* se comienza usar con su segundo sentido.

| Tomorrow | Morning |
| --- | --- |
| cras | mane |
| cras | maneana |
| cras [mañana] | mañana |
| mañana | mañana |

El sentido de *"día después de hoy"* viene o de una contracción de la frase *"cras mañana"*, o simplemente un hipónimo para *cras*. Este fenómeno (usar la palabra para *"temprano en el día"* para referir al *"día después de hoy"*) ha pasado en muchas lenguas<sup>[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22024/are-tomorrow-and-morning-etymologically-related) [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/7nc73e/why_are_the_words_for_morning_and_tomorrow_often/) [3](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/connection-between-tomorrow-and-morning-in-many-languages.3290707/)</sup>, ej:

- `Germanic` morgen/morgen <sup>(Danish, Dutch, German, Old English, Yiddish ( מאָרגן‎‎ (morgn)))</sup>
- `Finnish` huomen/huomenna
- `Arabic` buqra/buqra <sup>(Lebanese)</sup>

y en casi todas las lenguas romances (salvo el sardo, que es muy conservador):

- en la mayoría de las lenguas [iberorromances](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_iberorromances), hay un doble de palabras derivadas de *mane* para las dos significaciones
- en la mayoría de las lenguas [galorromances](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_galorromances) y [italo-dálmatas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_italo-d%C3%A1lmatas), la palabra derivada de *de + mane* ha tomado solo el sentido de *'el próximo día'* y una nueva palabra derivada de [*mātūtīnus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matutinus) (de *Mātūta*, la diosa de la mañana) ha suplido la definición original

[image]

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de ukemi a la pregunta que enlazas ([Origin of the grammar of "mañana por X"-type phrases?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26924/origin-of-the-grammar-of-ma%C3%B1ana-por-x-type-phrases/26927#26927)) ya recoge dos aspectos interesantes: 
1) Que también ocurre en gallego
2) Unas referencias al Poema del Mio Cid en las que se utiliza **cras** para "el día siguiente al de hoy" y **mañana** para "a primera hora del día"

Comment: asi que "mañana" antes se decía "cras" ? cras temprano : mañana temprano ? cras por la mañana: mañana por la mañana ?

Answer (score 2):

Muy interesante todas las aportaciones.

Yo quiero participar con otra idea.

Aclaró que no soy ningún estudioso de lingüística, ni de etimologías, solo soy un usuario del español.

Creo que la explicación más sencilla es que la palabra cras sale sobrando.

Me explico a continuación:

Todo día empieza cuando sale el Sol
Toda mañana inicia cuando sale  del Sol

Conclusión:

Cuando sale el Sol inicia un nuevo día.

¿Cuándo sale el Sol?
Por la mañana

Por lo tanto por la mañana se cambia de día

Y así fue que “cras” salió sobrando.

¿Cuando harás esto?

Mañana, es decir, en cuanto salga el Sol, en cuanto termine este día (Que ya comenzó) y comience el que sigue (que no ha comenzado) o sea el siguiente día o “cras”.

Si digo que haré algo en la mañana quiero decir que lo haré justo en el periodo de tiempo en el que inicia un nuevo día.

Si la mañana de hoy ya feneció por lógica lo haré la mañana siguiente o “cras” pero no hace falta decirlo, simplemente se entiende que así será.