# ¿Existe en español alguna palabra no en desuso derivada del latín "cras"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, latín

Hemos visto en preguntas anteriores que en latín se distinguía la palabra *mañana* como "a primera hora del día" de *mañana* como "el día siguiente al actual". En este último caso la palabra usada era *cras*.

Hoy día el DLE sigue recogiendo *[cras](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BCPZhOq)* como sinónimo de *mañana* pero está marcada como en desuso. Sin embargo, ¿existe alguna palabra de uso común hoy día que derive de *cras*?

Comment: Referencias para el futuro: [¿Qué significado de “mañana” fue antes: el de “día siguiente” o el de “primera hora del día”? ¿Cuándo y cómo se originó el otro?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26931/1674)

Answer (score 3):

Sí que existe:

> **[procrastinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UG8b6uO)**
>
> Del lat. *procrastināre*.
>
> 1. tr. Diferir, aplazar.

El DLE no da más etimología que esa, pero en Etymonline [podemos ver](https://www.etymonline.com/word/procrastination) que la palabra *procrastināre* significa literalmente "posponer hasta mañana" y viene de *pro* 'para' y *crastinus* 'que pertenece al día siguiente', siendo esta un derivado de *cras* 'mañana'.

Comment: ¡Qué buena! Y buceando en Etymonline me encuentro con [_manana_](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manana): _from Spanish mañana, "tomorrow," from cras manñana, literally "tomorrow early," from Vulgar Latin *maneana "early," from Latin mane "in the morning," from PIE *ma- "good," with notion of "occurring at a good time, timely, early"_.